# rChart nPlot - update yAxis label

Tags: r, rcharts

I am currently using nPlot from rCharts package and how do I add $ signs to the y Axis?

I am thinking I need something like `n1$yAxis(labels = ...)` but I don't think nPlot supports this?

```
test <- data.frame(object = c("A", "B"), price = c(111333, 876176))
test$Test <- "TEST"
n1 <- nPlot(price~Test, group = "object", data = test, type = "multiBarChart")
```

Also, it looks like nPlot is rounding to 5 significant figures (initially thought it was rounding to the nearest 10), is there a way of displaying the full value?

Thanks,

Comment: do you want a dollar sign into the y-axis title?

Comment: I just pushed a fix to the `dev` branch of `rCharts`. It uses 13 digits while converting to json, and can be controlled using `options('rcharts.digits')`.

Comment: @Michele I want to add dollar signs to the y axis labels, e.g. something like scale_y_continuous("Price", labels = dollar) from scales package

Comment: @Ramnath so do I have re-install the rCharts package?

Comment: Yes. `devtools::install_github('rCharts', 'ramnathv', ref = 'dev')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am posting my comment as a full solution so that it is easier for others looking for it.

```
require(rCharts) # install the latest from the dev branch
test <- data.frame(object = c("A", "B"), price = c(111333, 876176))
test$Test <- "TEST"
n1 <- nPlot(price~Test, group = "object", data = test, type = "multiBarChart")
n1$yAxis(tickFormat = "#! function(d) {return '$' + d} !#")
```

Comment: Thanks Ramnath, that added the dollar sign but got rid of ',' the 1,000 separator. How do I add $ and , separator at the same time?

Comment: try 

n1$yAxis(tickFormat = "#! function(d) {return '$' + d3.format(',.2f')(d)} !#")

Comment: that is amazing. Never done anything more than running just the examples... through the `yAxis` method you provide named strings (containing JS functions!) to define each part (tick format here) of the `yAxis`. @Ramnath where can I find a something more detailed about rCharts? The r documentation for `rCharts` is very limited. Thanks

Comment: @Michele Documentation is thin currently, and we are working on it.

Comment: ok, thanks again. For now I'll go through all the question tagged `rCharts` :)

Comment: If you have questions, raise them on the github page for rCharts. We usually resolve things quickly :) But docs are on the way!

Comment: For reference, here's how I managed to do percentages, following the ideas in this post `n1$yAxis(tickFormat = "#! function(d) {return d3.format('.0%')(d)} !#")`